# The ListView doesn't show me a list with names from database. I use SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, listview

im trying to implement database to my aplication. It is first time when i am doing this.
I have a layout with list view and im using a SimpleCoursorAdapter to transport data from dataBase to my ListView. The aplication doesn't show anything. ListView is empty i don't know why.

It is my TopLevelActivity

```
public class TopLevelActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_level);

        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener =
                                                    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView,
                                            View v,
                                            int position,
                                            long id) {
                        if(position == 0){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(TopLevelActivity.this, DrinkCategoryActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        if(position == 1){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(TopLevelActivity.this, SnacksCategoryActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    }
                };
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_options);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }
}
```

xml from TopLevelActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TopLevelActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/starbuzz_logo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/starbuzz_logo"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/options"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

the DrinkCategoryActivity i think here is somethink wrong

```
public class DrinkCategoryActivity extends Activity {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink_category);
        ListView listDrinks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_drinks);

        SQLiteOpenHelper coffeinaDatabaseHelper = new CoffeinaDatabaseHelper(this);
        try {
            db = coffeinaDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            cursor = db.query("DRINK",
                    new String[]{"_id", "NAME"},
                    null, null, null, null, null);

            SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter
                    (this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            cursor,
                            new String[]{"NAME"},
                            new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0
                            );
            listDrinks.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Baza danych jest niedostepna",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }



    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener =
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listDrinks,
                                        View itemView,
                                        int position,
                                        long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DrinkCategoryActivity.this,
                            DrinkActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKID, (int) id);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            };

        listDrinks.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

}

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

xml from DrinkCategoryActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DrinkCategoryActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_drinks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>





</LinearLayout>
```

DrinkAtivity

```
public class DrinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_DRINKID = "drinkId";





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);

        int drinkId = (Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKID);
        
        SQLiteOpenHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new CoffeinaDatabaseHelper(this);

        try{
            SQLiteDatabase db = starbuzzDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("DRINK",
                                        new String[]{"NAME", "DESCRIPTION", "IMAGE_RESORUCE_ID"},
                    "_id = ?",
                    new String[]{Integer.toString(drinkId)},
                    null, null, null);


            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                String nameText = cursor.getString(0);
                String descriptionText = cursor.getString(1);
                int photoId = cursor.getInt(2);

                TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
                name.setText(nameText);

                TextView description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);
                description.setText(descriptionText);

                ImageView photo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.latte);
                photo.setImageResource(photoId);
                photo.setContentDescription(nameText);

            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

        }catch (SQLiteException e){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Bada danych jest niedostepna",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }


    }
}
```

xml from DrinkActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DrinkActivity">
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/latte"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

and my DataBaseHelper and here can be also somethink wrong.
The complicator doesn't show any error.

```
package com.hfad.coffeina;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class CoffeinaDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "coffeina";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;

    CoffeinaDatabaseHelper(Context context){

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    public  void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        updateMyDatabase(db, 0, DB_VERSION);

    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
            updateMyDatabase(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    private static void insertDrink(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String description,
                                       int resourceId){
        ContentValues drinkValues = new ContentValues();
        drinkValues.put("NAME", name);
        drinkValues.put("DESCRIPTION", description);
        drinkValues.put("IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID", resourceId);
        db.insert("DRINK", null, drinkValues);

    }

    private void updateMyDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        if(oldVersion < 1){
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DRINK (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    +"NAME TEXT, "
                    +"DESCRIPTON TEXT , "
                    +"IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID INTEGER);");
            insertDrink(db, "Latte", "Czarne espresso z gorącym mlekiem i mleczną pianką.",
                    R.drawable.latte);
            insertDrink(db, "Cappucciono", "Czarne espresso z dużą ilościa spienionego mleka",
                    R.drawable.cappuccino);
            insertDrink(db, "Espresso", "Czarna kawa ze świeżo mielonych ziaren najwyższej jakości.",
                    R.drawable.filter);
        }
        if(oldVersion < 2){
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE DRINK ADD COLUMN FAVORITE NUMERIC;");
        }
    }

}
```

The print Screen from emulator [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArKWp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Issue**

I believe that your prime issue is that in the DRINK table you define a column name  using **`+"DESCRIPTON TEXT , "`** yet you refer to the DESCRIPTION column (t**i**on as opposed to ton) elsewhere including when inserting the 3 initial rows. Hidden/disguised because they are in try .... catch constructs.

Note that wrapping SQLite stuff in try .... catch is typically unhelpful and leads to confusion, especially if the log isn't checked when testing.

That is the log would show something like :-

```
07-21 17:29:20.748 4340-4340/a.a.so68457788javesqlitelistview E/SQLiteLog: (1) table DRINK has no column named DESCRIPTION
07-21 17:29:20.749 4340-4340/a.a.so68457788javesqlitelistview E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting NAME=Latte DESCRIPTION=Czarne espresso z gorącym mlekiem i mleczną pianką. IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID=10
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table DRINK has no column named DESCRIPTION (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO DRINK(NAME,DESCRIPTION,IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID) VALUES (?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at a.a.so68457788javesqlitelistview.CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.insertDrink(CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.java:32)
        at a.a.so68457788javesqlitelistview.CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.updateMyDatabase(CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.java:42)
        at a.a.so68457788javesqlitelistview.CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.onCreate(CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.java:18)
```

As such the database will be empty and hence why the ListView shows nothing.

I would suggest ALWAYS using a single definition for database components and ALWAYS referring to the components using the single definition.

**Suggested Fix/Improvment**

Perhaps consider using :-

```
class CoffeinaDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "coffeina";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String  DRINK_TABLENAME = "DRINK";
    public static final String DRINK_ID_COLUMN = BaseColumns._ID; // Android _id column name
    public static final String DRINK_NAME_COLUMN = "NAME";
    public static final String DRINK_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN = "DESCRIPTION";
    public static final String DRINK_IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID_COLUMN = "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID";
    public static final String DRINK_FAVORITE_COLUMN = "FAVOURITE";

    CoffeinaDatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    public  void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        updateMyDatabase(db, 0, DB_VERSION);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        updateMyDatabase(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    private static void insertDrink(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String description,
                                    int resourceId){
        ContentValues drinkValues = new ContentValues();
        drinkValues.put(DRINK_NAME_COLUMN, name);
        drinkValues.put(DRINK_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN, description);
        drinkValues.put(DRINK_IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID_COLUMN, resourceId);
        db.insert(DRINK_TABLENAME, null, drinkValues);
    }

    private void updateMyDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        if(oldVersion < 1){
            /* no need for autoincrement id's will be generated without the overheads 
                check https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html for details/why
            */
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DRINK_TABLENAME + " (" + DRINK_ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                    + DRINK_NAME_COLUMN + " TEXT,"
                    + DRINK_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN +" TEXT , "
                    + DRINK_IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER);");
            insertDrink(db, "Latte", "Czarne espresso z gorącym mlekiem i mleczną pianką.",10);
            insertDrink(db, "Cappucciono", "Czarne espresso z dużą ilościa spienionego mleka", 11);
            insertDrink(db, "Espresso", "Czarna kawa ze świeżo mielonych ziaren najwyższej jakości.", 12);
        }
        if(oldVersion < 2){
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE DRINK ADD COLUMN " + DRINK_FAVORITE_COLUMN + " NUMERIC;");
        }
    }
}
```

- **NOTE** for testing the image resource id's have been made up, these will need to be changed to reflect your original code.

And then subsequently referring the the database components elsewhere using the constants. For example consider the following version of the **DrinkCategoryActivity** class :-

```
public class DrinkCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CoffeinaDatabaseHelper coffeinaDatabaseHelper; //<<<<< ADDED you want instance of YOUR helper not an SQLiteOpenHelper
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter; //<<<<< Better here, more scope
    ListView listDrinks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink_category);
        listDrinks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_drinks);
        // SQLiteOpenHelper coffeinaDatabaseHelper = new CoffeinaDatabaseHelper(this);
        coffeinaDatabaseHelper = new CoffeinaDatabaseHelper(this);
        db = coffeinaDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // get readable will typically get writeable anyway
        setOrRefreshListView();
    }

    private void setOrRefreshListView() {
        cursor = db.query(CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.DRINK_TABLENAME,
                new String[]{"_id", CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.DRINK_NAME_COLUMN},
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor,
                    new String[]{"NAME"},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
            listDrinks.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            listDrinks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DrinkActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKID, l);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else {
            listAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        }
    }

    /* If returning to Activity (from DrinkActivity) refresh the ListView
        just in case it has changed
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setOrRefreshListView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Using the above then :-

[image]

**Additional**

taking the above further then a working (albeit without the images) and more concise version of the DrinkActity is :-

```
public class DrinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_DRINKID = "drinkId";
    CoffeinaDatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    TextView name,description;
    ImageView photo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);
        long drinkId = this.getIntent().getLongExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKID,-1); // Should be LONG
        DBHelper = new CoffeinaDatabaseHelper(this);
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        name = this.findViewById(R.id.name);
        description = this.findViewById(R.id.description);
        Cursor cursor = db.query(CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.DRINK_TABLENAME,
                null,
                CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.DRINK_ID_COLUMN +" = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(drinkId)}, // cope with Long
                null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.DRINK_NAME_COLUMN)));
            description.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.DRINK_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN)));
            //<<<<< COMMENTED OUT FOR TESTING (as invalid resource id's have been used) >>>>>
            //photo.setImageResource(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.DRINK_IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID_COLUMN)));
            //photo.setContentDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CoffeinaDatabaseHelper.DRINK_NAME_COLUMN)));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bada danych jest niedostepna", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        cursor.close();
        //db.close(); don't close, resource expensive to open
    }
}
```

So selecting Latte gives :-

[image]

Comment: i chech your fix version. First i look what you did i am implement it and it is still not working than i copy your code and pase to my android studio and still is the same Table is empty and ListView show nothink but when i check on the tablet emulator than is working on the phone no but why

Comment: @JacobNatural you probably need to re-install on the phone. Once the database is created if stays there, so onCreate doesn't run again. Re-install deletes the database.

Comment: i can't open the cursor. My DrinkActivity doesn't work. I copy your code and still not. I deletes aplication from phone install again but still nothing.

Comment: okey i fix the problem. When i create the table i had PRIMARY KEY instead of INTEGER PRIMARY KEY